# Preserving commit ID-tag with "git am"

Tags: git, version-control, git-am

I attempted (on a small test repository) to export the repository into a series of `.patch` files generated with a `git format-patch` command for each commit and then to reconstitute the repository by using "git init" on an empty directory followed by a `git apply` command for each patch file. It worked --- only one problem ---- when `git am` applies a patch to a repository instead of preserving the patch's ID-tag, it generates a new one. This can be a problem later on, as it can make it difficult to determine which commits are redundant and which ones are not.

As for why I don't use normal methods of cloning a repository like `git clone` -- the answer is that *generally* speaking, I *do* use `git clone` to clone a repository - but I have very specific reasons at the moment to try to see if I can do it this way that are too long to go into detail here (though I may *allude* to the reason later on in this question) --- and not only are those reasons too long, but I fail to see how their final details can affect what the correct answer to this question is.

However, if you tell me that `.patch` isn't the correct file-format to use for this purpose, that I'm open to. What is most essential that I want to do is:

1. Extract individual commits to the repo to individual files -- and to know the order of those files in the repo history etc.
2. Be able to completely reconstitute the repo based on those extracted versions of the commits
3. Later on be able to "de-canonize" any commit that I identify that shouldn't have been made (and which keeping in the repository's history would not be worth the bloat it would cause to the project history-size) so that I can re-constitute the repo without the "de-canonized" commits. (And by the way, aspect #3 ties in very much to the reason why I want to be able to do this.)

Comment: Surround inline code with backticks (`\``) for improved formatting.

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% clear what you are asking here.  I'm going to presume that when you say "commit ID-tag" you mean SHA.  And I don't know at all what you mean by "patch ID-tag".

So guessing ...

When you create a commit in git it has 6 pieces of meta-data attached to it.  Those are Author Name/Email/Time and Committer Name/Email/Time.  If you are creating a new commit from scratch the author name/email and committer name/email will both match.

They don't have to do.  You can override them via GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and similar environmental variables.  Of if you cherry-pick or rebase it will modify them.

When you run `git format-patch` it doesn't provide you with the committer information *at all*.
Likewise when you run `git am` it doesn't look for the committer information, instead overwriting it with the name and email of whomever is running `git am`.  This will result in a different SHA being created if that information changes.

No easy way to get around it (you would have to hack both format-patch and am to preserve comitter info.  However, instead of comparing the commit SHAs you could calculate the commit Patch ID (git patch-id) and compare those.  They should be identical.

Comment: Basically what I want to be able to do is this --- I want to be able to distill a commit into a file of *any* format --- so as to allow alternate methods of transporting commits from one site to another (other than the conventional "git-pull" and "git-push"). Any file-format will do as long as it (a) uses one file per commit and (b) that file contains *everyting* that is part of the commit - including who made the commit, where, and any unique identifiers for the commit.

Comment: Oh one more thing ---- when I say "one file per commit" I don't mean that the file-format has to *limit* it to one file per commit (though it's okay if it does) -- all that is necessary is that the file-format includes the *option* of having it be one file per commit.

Comment: Do you care about bloating disk space?  You could always just dump out the commit object, and then all the trees and blobs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What you said just went straight over my head --- and I strongly suspect that someone who would understand what you meant by  "the commit object, and then all the trees and blobs" would be someone who wouldn't need to ask this question in the first place. So could you explain what you mean? You've lost me.

Comment: I don't know how much I can simplify it in a comment.  Are you concerned about recreating identical commits?  Meaning the exact same SHA?  You can read about git objects here http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects